# How to include css file in site template

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, site-template

I have created a team site in Sharepoint 2013 which I want to save as a template. I have modified some html in master page and home page of the site from Sharepoint Designer and created a custom **style.css** file in **style library** of the site and saved it as template.

When I create a new site from that template, its getting all the html modifications but no style as it doesn't have the style.css file, I have to manually add the css file to style library to make it working.

How can I include my custom css files in my site template so that my new site is created with my custom style. is this possible and how to do it.

Comment: In the site where you do the customisations and save a template, I believe you customise its Master Page and hence that site should have a css in the styles library. When you save that site as a template and create a new site based on that template, does it have the css in style library?

Comment: I have created a new css file and saved it in style library, and used that file for styling my template site, when i create new site from template, it doesnt have my custom css file in its style library. is there a way i can add it automatically when i create site from template?

Comment: When you create the site template, do you select the option to Include content?

Comment: tried using 'include content' and it worked like a charm, thanks a lot Manu, if u can post this as an answer i will mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the record, selecting the option to include content while saving the site as template solves the issue.

Good to know that your issue is resolved.